# How to calculate frequency for PWM design

Tags: pwm

I would like to create a PWM controller for an open loop galvo-mirror. The similar questions involve motors and I can not directly use that approach to galvo-mirror which only deflects, not rotates.

It should deflect at +-1023 discrete angles, where the |1023| value would represent the maximum deflection. A particular period would start from -1023, -1022 ...0 ... 1022, 1023, 1022... -1023. So, the angular rotation would look like a triangular wave.

If I understand correctly, for a particular deflection angle I must have pulses of particular length. Thus, for 1023 angles there should be 1023 pulse width variations.

Now, the time between two successive consecutive positions is 100us. How to calculate the number of pulses within the 100us period (PWM frequency, switching) necessary to maintain that particular deflection angle, so the mirror does not jitter?

If I use the suggestion f>R/L from [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/90647/how-to-calculate-switching-frequecncy) question, then the minimum switching frequency is 1400Hz. But that does not look right, since I must have at least 10kHz switching frequency. In the 10kHz case, there will be only 1 pulse to support a 100us period deflection. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need between 1 and 1023 pulses in a ~100usec period, then your PWM clock needs to be 10.24MHz (10MHz should be fine).

The frequency would thus be fixed (9.766kHz) but the width (that's the 'W' in PWM) of the pulses would vary from 0 to 1023 x 100ns units wide in a 1024ns total mark + space width.

Comment: 1 is understood - that's the minimum. But based what did you select the upper value for the number of pulses (1023)?

Comment: That's for generating currents with a resolution of 1 part in 1024 (10 bits). If you need 1 part in 2048 (+/- 10 bits) then you either need to switch the polarity and have a 10-bit PWM or to use an 11-bit PWM and 20MHz. At some point that becomes problematic.

Comment: Ok. I think, I get it.

Comment: Wait, something does not make sense here. Let's say I want to keep the mirror deflected at position "1" for 100us period. That means, the pulse width should be 1 unit of the PWM clock - 1*100ns. So, i give it a 100ns pulse, the mirror deflects somewhere, and then there is LOW signal for the rest of the period (99,900ns). During this time the mirror will fall back to the initial position instead of staying at position 1. I am confused now.

Comment: My assumption was that the mirror will not move substantially in 100us. If it you need it to move that fast (and it is possible) you have to have an even faster PWM.

Comment: I am looking at something like [these](http://www.camtech.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=88&Itemid=76) scanners. They have old open loop ones too. Initially, I would generate a voltage ramp of 1024 discrete steps using DAC and this would make the mirror to sweep across the mechanical angle. So, the duration of each step was 100us and the duration of the ramp was about 102.4ms. Then I was suggested to use PWM, which is where I am now. So, to substitute a 100us DC voltage I would need enough pulses to look like the 100us DC, right?

Comment: So, using the earlier mentioned equation f>R/L=7/0.005=1400. That means I need 1400 pulses withing a 100us period. And, to get 1024 resolution, I would need 1400*10MHz=14GHz PWM clock. I am wrong.(